# Set radio button value by manipulating URL

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm sure all of you manipulated parameterized URLs to change how a particular website (that you didn't create) looks. For instance, you want to see more than the maximum number of results on a page, so you do something like:

```
http://www.example.com/search.jsp?results=1000
```

Or to jump quickly to the 1500th result:

```
http://www.example.com/search.jsp?startat=1500&results=50
```

So with that in mind, I am trying to create a link to some search results of a webpage, but I need to set the value of a  radio button to get the results I am looking for. I found the field names by using Chrome Developer Tools because the parameters do not show in the URL, even though I can search by manipulating the URL using the fields I found. So far I have:

```
http://www.example.com/blah/search.jsp?vstr4=A123456789
```

where `vstr4` is the text field to search within. But there is also a radio button, `vint2`. In the HTML,

```
<input type=​"radio" name=​"vint2" value=​"0" checked >​ "Type 1"
<input type=​"radio" name=​"vint2" value=​"1">​ "Type 2"
```

In this case, `Type 1` is default, but I need the radio button set to `Type 2` to get what I am looking for. So my question is, **how can I set the radio button at index 1's checked property?** I've tried stuff like:

```
http://www.example.com/blah/search.jsp?vstr4=A123456789&vint2=1
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/blah/search.jsp?vstr4=A123456789&vint2[1]checked="checked"
```

and similar. I'm not sure how to access the properties of a particular index of a radio button. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons are just name/value pairs.  They're more like oddly shaped text inputs than anything else.  Set "vint2" to "1" and you're fine.

Comment: That doesn't work: `http://www.example.com/blah/search.jsp?vstr4=A123456789&vint2=1` I think with radio buttons, the value is really the index, setting it does not imply setting checked=checked.

Comment: It doesn't set the thing to checked necessarily, no, but the name/value pair is what the radio button generates when submitted.  I don't believe that you can control the position of the radio button on the page with query params unless the page has been set up with a server-side dynamic setup that lets you.  If the radio button is actually firing javascript, rather than generating data for form submission, then there's no way to do it with query params - it's listening for the onchange.

Comment: Yeah okay. It doesn't work so that must be the case. The first thing I tried was `vint2=1` and the results don't appear as expected so I tried all that other weird stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
&vint2=1
```

to the url!